# JavaScript framework for HTML5 browser application

Tags: javascript, html, browser, frameworks, client

we plan develop application that will, like many other modern applications is divided into two parts: Client and Server.

Client running in the browser (pure HTML5, CSS, JS) communicate with the server using JSON API.

The target group is users are using a modern browser (Chrome, Firefox> = 4, Opera, IE> = 9 ..).

Client will be authorize with server using OAuth and should be able to as well as offline mode.

So I ask you about a JavaScript framework for browser like client application?

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) which is a clean and simple to use MVC javascript. You should try this first. The author is also coffeescript's author. I'm currently learning backbone, and it's quite nice and  flexible.

You can search the backbone's document for Todos example, it will be easier to learn from example :)

Answer (score 0):

[Extjs4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/whats-new-in-ext-js-4/) provides MVC Application Architecture & allows the separation of data management, logic and interface elements.

Check out sample & demos [here.](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/)